# not giving the result as expected when the method is being invoked

Tags: java, spring

I am working on spring application, I want to trigger the aspect @Before whenever any of the setxx(..) methods are being called in the class.When the Details class is executed, the SetterInterceptor @Before aspect is not being called.

I have the below classes:

```
package com.mypack;
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }

    public void setId(String id) { this.id = id; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }
    public String toString() { return "Person[" + id + ",  
   + firstName + ", " + lastName+ "]"; }
}
```

Details class:

```
package com.mypack;
public class Details extends Person{

    private String address;
    private String contactNum;
    //getters and setters
    public String toString() { return "Details[" + address + ", 
    " + contactNum+ "]"; }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Details obj1 = new Details();
    obj1.setAddress("xx 202");
    obj1.setContactNum("2124551234");
    obj1.setId("242");
    obj1.setFirstName("John");
    obj1.setLastName("John");

    Details obj2 = new Details();
    obj2.setAddress("ASDf 202");
    obj2.setContactNum("234544565656");
    obj2.setId("23689");
    obj2.setFirstName("Sam");
    obj2.setLastName("S");

    System.out.println("obj1 : " + obj1);
    System.out.println("obj2 : " + obj2);

    obj2.setFirstName("Samuel");
}

}
```

SetterInterceptor  class:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class SetterInterceptor {
     @Before("execution(* com.mypack.Details.set*(*))")
        public void before(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object[] signatureArgs = joinPoint.getArgs();
            for (Object signatureArg : signatureArgs) {
                Person obj = (Person) signatureArg;
                System.out.println("Before : " + obj.getFirstName() + " ---- "
                        + obj.getId());

            }

        }
}
```

Any inputs are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation on Spring AOP (emphasis mine):

> Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points
>   (advising the execution of **methods on Spring beans**)

In other words any method calls that you want intercepted need to be on beans instantiated by Spring.

In your example the application is not even a Spring application (you don't have an ApplicationContext) and you create the instance of Details by using `new`.

Comment: so will the example shown in this link doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31503041/spring-aop-get-old-field-value-before-calling-the-setter

Comment: You need to use `AspectJ`

Comment: Can you please provide any link.@GovindaSakhare